# I am having problems with Headers in PHP mail

Tags: php, email

I am having a problem getting the header to work in the mail PHP. It is actually a contact form and the "From" parameter is essential. Here is part of the code:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " . $name . " <".$from.">\r\n";



        // If there are no errors, send the email
        if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errVerify ) {
        $success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

            // redirect to success page 
            if ($success){
              $result='<div style="margin-top:20px" class="alert alert-success">Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you as soon as possible.</div>';
            }
            else{
              $result='<div style="margin-top:20px" class="alert alert-success">There was a problem.</div>';
            }
        }
```

However, this will only print out the result as unsuccessful. But when I remove the header from mail(), the email gets sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the MIME-Version. Try with something like this:

```
    $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";        
    $headers .= "From: ".$name."\n";
```

Anyway sending mails is more complex than it seems, as for example some servers only accept \n instead of \r\n. It is usualy much better to use robust libraries like phpmailer or swiftmail.

Comment: The order of headers doesn't matter.

Comment: @Barmar you are totaly right, didn't know it, thanks. I have just edited the answer.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Apparently, my web server doesn't allow me to send an email from domains other than the domain hosting the script. The thing is I own both domains. Any idea how to fix this? Do I need to use STMP authentication?